# Swift: Convert Int into Date

Tags: swift, date

I have an Int that I'm trying to convert into a date with a format of mm-dd-yyyy.

```
var dateTime = 1545215400000

let timeInterval = Double(dateTime)
let myNSDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval) //Says its "Oct 29, 52338 at 6:00 AM"
print(myNSDate) //prints out 52338-10-29 10:00:00 +0000

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(timeInterval)") prints out nil
```

The date is completely wrong because the article for this date came out today. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to divide the number of milliseconds by 1000. `1545215400000/1000` the resulting date would be `"Dec 19, 2018 at 8:30 AM Brazilian standard time"`

Comment: Once you get the date object you can use DateFormatter's method `string(from: Date)` to format your date as needed